# How to verify whether service exists in Services.msc

Tags: c#, wmi

I am using following code to get the path of the service...

```
 string ServicePath = string.Format("Win32_Service.Name=\"{0}\"", "MyService");
 var WMiObject = new ManagementObject(ServicePath);
 string PathName = (string)WMiObject.GetPropertyValue("PathName");
```

Now if the service is not available then the call wmiObject.getPropertyValue("PathName")
will throw the ManagementException..

In my case i need to assign the HardCoded path if the service is not available..
How to achieve that??
Please guide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use a try block around your WMiObject.GetPropertyValue call and assign the constant value in the catch block.

```
string PathName;
try
{
    PathName = (string)WMiObject.GetPropertyValue("PathName");
}
catch (ManagementException)
{
    PathName = "my constant path value";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string Name = "MyService";
ServiceController service = ServiceController
                        .GetServices()
                        .Where(s => s.ServiceName == Name).FirstOrDefault();

if(null != service)
{
    // service exists
}
```